# Issues with \defbibentryset

Tags: biblatex

Using `biblatex` for my bibliography. When defining a `\defbibentryset` and using the `\citeauthor` command, it only cites the authors of the first key in the set, instead of all. Moreover, it ignores my `\AtEveryBibitem` directives (*i.e.,* it doesn't suppress fields such as ISSN or DOI). Any ideas on how to address those?

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Iftimie.etal-largetimebehavior2003,
  author = {Iftimie, Drago\c{s} and Lopes Filho, Milton C. and Nussenzveig Lopes,
    Helena J.},
  title = {On the large-time behavior of two-dimensional vortex dynamics},
  journal = {Physica D -- Nonlinear Phenomena},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {179},
  doi = {10.1016/S0167-2789(03)00028-9},
  pages = {153--160}
}

@ARTICLE{Iftimie-LargeTimeBehavior2003,
  author = {Iftimie, Drago\c{s} and Lopes Filho, Milton C. and Nussenzveig Lopes,
    Helena J.},
  title = {Large Time Behavior for Vortex Evolution in the Half-Plane},
  journal = {Communications in Mathematical Physics},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {237},
  pages = {441--469},
  number = {3},
  doi = {10.1007/s00220-003-0843-3},
  issn = {0010-3616}
}

@ARTICLE{Iftimie.Kelliher-RemarksVanishingObstacle2009,
  author = {Iftimie, Drago\c{s} and Kelliher, James~P.},
  title = {Remarks on the Vanishing Obstacle Limit for a 3D Viscous Incompressible
    Fluid},
  journal = {Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {137},
  pages = {685--694},
  number = {2}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,%
            sorting=nyt,sortcase=false,refsegment=section,%
            citereset=none,subentry,%
            backend=biber]{biblatex}


% Biblatex
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibentryset{Iftimie}{Iftimie-LargeTimeBehavior2003,Iftimie.etal-largetimebehavior2003,Iftimie.Kelliher-RemarksVanishingObstacle2009}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}


\begin{document}

\section{Intro}


\par \citeauthor{Iftimie} wrote some papers \autocite{Iftimie-LargeTimeBehavior2003,Iftimie.etal-largetimebehavior2003}. Then another \autocite{Iftimie.Kelliher-RemarksVanishingObstacle2009}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={References},segment=1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An entry of the `@set` type has the special field `entryset` defined and inherits data from the first entry in the set, but otherwise it is treated like any other individual entry. So `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\citeauthor` act only on the `@set` entry, not on the set members. The command `\entryset{<precode>}{<postcode>}` roughly executes the following for each member of the current set:

```
<precode>
\usedriver{}{<member entrytype>}
<postcode>
```

To act on the set members you'll need to access a few internals:

```
\makeatletter
\def\UseBibitemHook{\csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}}
\def\nodriver{\let\blx@driver\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

The `\entryset` command is used in the `set` bibliography driver defined by `numeric.bbx`. The `\AtEveryBibitem` hook can be added to `<precode>`:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset
    {\UseBibitemHook%
     \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
        \setunit*{\addnbspace}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
```

However you might be better off just loading biblatex with the option settings:

```
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false
```

The `\citeauthor` command from `biblatex.def` can be redefined to act on the set members, instead of the `@set` entry itself:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifentrytype{set}
     {\nodriver%
      \def\namelist{}%
      \setcounter{setcount}{0}%
      \setcounter{settotal}{0}%
      \entryset{\indexnames[count:labelname]{labelname}}{\unspace}%
      \def\namelist{}%
      \entryset{%
        \ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
        \printnames[set:labelname]{labelname}}{\unspace}}
     {\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
      \printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcounter{setcount}
\newcounter{settotal}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{count:labelname}{%
  \ifinnamelist{#1#3#5#7}{}{%
    \namelistadd{#1#3#5#7}%
    \stepcounter{settotal}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{set:labelname}{%
  \ifinnamelist{#1#3#5#7}{}{%
    \namelistadd{#1#3#5#7}%
    \stepcounter{setcount}%
    \renewbibmacro*{name:delim}[1]{\usebibmacro{set:name:delim}{#1}}%
    \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
      \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
    \or
      \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
    \or
      \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
    \fi}}

\newbibmacro*{set:name:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{setcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumless{\value{setcount}}{\value{settotal}}
       {\multinamedelim}
       {\finalnamedelim}}
    {}}

\newrobustcmd*{\namelistadd}[1]{\listxadd{\namelist}{\detokenize{#1}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\ifinnamelist}[1]{\xifinlist{\detokenize{#1}}{\namelist}}
```

Comment: The `\nodriver` is a very neat solution. Though, the solution does not combine all the authors in a group in a single list (not sure whether this is what the OP wants).

Comment: @Guido The approach could be adapted to combine the author lists via multiple calls to \entryset. Consistent name list disambiguation probably won't be possible under any approach with out some modifications to the bib file.

Comment: @Audrey: I really like your answer concerning the first question: no need for extra packages, and it will automatically take into account other `\AtEveryBibitem` directives I may add (I also suppress month fields f.ex. for which there is no package option like there is for doi/url/isbn), but Guido's answer addresses the second one better, IMHO. Should I split my question into two? And let Guido move his answer to the second question?

Comment: @ChristophB. Up to you. In any case I'll find some time this week to revise this answer to demonstrate the solution described in my earlier comment.

Comment: This works really well, thank you! Applying your code to my example case however, I have an extra space appearing after the (now correct) last name, and I've no idea where that comes from.

Comment: @ChristophB. There are two extraneous spaces - before and after the `\citeauthor`. The first is due to a missing `%`, the second generated by `\entryset`. I'll fix them in a bit.

Answer (score 5):

To address the issue of removing `doi`,`issn`, and `url` one can load the `xpatch` packages (i.e., `\usepackage{xpatch}`) and then use

```
\xpatchbibdriver{set}
  {\printfield}
  {\clearfield{doi}\clearfield{issn}\clearfield{url}\printfield}
  {}
  {}
```

Here is a solution to cite all authors in an `entryset`. The field `labelname` is created when parsing the `bib` files to create the `bbl` file. In `bbl` contains the information only about the authors of the first entry in a set. However, the `bbl` files contains `\set{key1,key2,...}` where each `keyN` is the key for an entry in the `entryset`.

The idea is then to use the `keyN` and to use them to create a list of all (author) names in the `entryset`.

We start by creating such a list, and at the same time we create two counters to hold the total number of authors and the counter for the current author.

```
\newcommand{\AuthorList}{}
\newcounter{AuthorSetCount}
\newcounter{CurrentAuthorSet}
```

These the counters are use to parse the elements of the author list and to insert the proper delimiter between authors. They are used as follows:

```
\newcommand{\mycount}[1]{\addtocounter{AuthorSetCount}{1}}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{#1
  \addtocounter{CurrentAuthorSet}{1}
  \ifnumequal{\value{CurrentAuthorSet}}{\value{AuthorSetCount}}
    {\addspace}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{CurrentAuthorSet}}{\value{AuthorSetCount}-1}
      {\addcomma\finalnamedelim}
      {\addcomma\addspace}%
    }%
}
```

To populate the list, we parse a name list. This is done by providing a formatting directive

```
\DeclareNameFormat{myentryset}{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\AuthorList}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\AuthorList}{#1}}%
}
```

The information in `\set{...}` is used by the `biblatex` command `\entryset{}{}`
where the two arguments are for `pre-code` and `postcode`. Unfortunately, for each entry in the set `\entryset` processes the driver for the entry. Thus we have to disable this and instead we populesate the list of author in the `entryset`. We introduce a conditional in the definitions of the commands used by `\entryset` to guard the operation when called in a citation or called in the bibliography. In a citation we execute the formatting instruction to populate the author list, otherwise the driver for the current entry is used.

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@entryset#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@imc@clearlist{pageref}%
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \def\abx@field@entrysetcount{1}%
     \blx@entryset@precode
     \ifcitation{\printnames[myentryset]{author}}%  Modified lines
       {\blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}}% Modified lines
     \blx@entryset@postcode%
     \endgroup}
    {}%
  \let\do\blx@entryset@i}

\def\blx@entryset@i#1{%
  \blx@imc@entrydata{#1}{%
    \blx@entryset@precode
    \ifcitation{\printnames[myentryset]{author}}%   Modified lines
       {\blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}}% Modified lines
    \blx@entryset@postcode}}
\makeatother
```

The final step is to create a specialised cite command

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\CiteAllAuthorsInSet}{}{%
  \ifentrytype{set}
    {\entryset{}{}
    \setcounter{AuthorSetCount}{0}
    \forlistloop{\mycount}{\AuthorList}%
    \forlistloop{\myitem}{\AuthorList}%
    \setcounter{CurrentAuthorSet}{0}
    \renewcommand{\AuthorList}{}}
    {\printfield{labelname}}%
}{}{}
```

Use

```
\begin{document}

\par \CiteAllAuthorsInSet{Iftimie} wrote some papers \dots

\par \citeauthor{Iftimie} wrote some papers \autocite{Iftimie-LargeTimeBehavior2003,Iftimie.etal-largetimebehavior2003}. Then another \autocite{Iftimie.Kelliher-RemarksVanishingObstacle2009}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={References},segment=1]

\end{document}
```

to see the difference between `\citeauthor` and `\CiteAllAuthorsInSet`.

[image]

Here is the full code

```
\xpatchbibdriver{set}{\printfield}{\clearfield{doi}\clearfield{issn}\clearfield{url}\printfield}{}{}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@entryset#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@imc@clearlist{pageref}%
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \def\abx@field@entrysetcount{1}%
     \blx@entryset@precode
     \ifcitation{\printnames[myentryset]{author}}
       {\blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \blx@entryset@postcode%
     \endgroup}
    {}%
  \let\do\blx@entryset@i}

\def\blx@entryset@i#1{%
  \blx@imc@entrydata{#1}{%
    \blx@entryset@precode
    \ifcitation{\printnames[myentryset]{author}}
       {\blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}}%
    \blx@entryset@postcode}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\AuthorList}{}

\DeclareNameFormat{myentryset}{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\AuthorList}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\AuthorList}{#1}}%
}

\newcounter{AuthorSetCount}
\newcounter{CurrentAuthorSet}
\newcommand{\mycount}[1]{\addtocounter{AuthorSetCount}{1}}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{#1
  \addtocounter{CurrentAuthorSet}{1}
  \ifnumequal{\value{CurrentAuthorSet}}{\value{AuthorSetCount}}
    {\addspace}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{CurrentAuthorSet}}{\value{AuthorSetCount}-1}
      {\addcomma\finalnamedelim}
      {\addcomma\addspace}%
    }%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\CiteAllAuthorsInSet}{}{%
  \ifentrytype{set}
    {\entryset{}{}
      \setcounter{AuthorSetCount}{0}
      \forlistloop{\mycount}{\AuthorList}%
      \forlistloop{\myitem}{\AuthorList}%
      \setcounter{CurrentAuthorSet}{0}%
      \renewcommand{\AuthorList}{}%
    }
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
}{}{}
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks Guido. See my question to Audrey regarding how I should handle this question.