# Different citation style options for footnotes and bibliography when using bibentryset?

Tags: bibtex, biber

I need to have numbered footnoted citations with the chem-acs style I found the answer for that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69249/biblatex-citation-appears-with-different-reference-marks)

My PI has asked me to have the title of the reference shown which I have done, but I wanted the title to show only for the bibliography not the footnotes which I figured out like so. `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}`

I want to have grouped citations which I have managed to implement with`\defbibentryset` I was having a problem with `\autocite` where every time I wanted to cite a grouped reference individually it would make another footnote I solved this by modifying `\cite` to give me a superscript mark.

Problem 1: The footnote citations from the `\defbibentryset` still have the title. I know it is something to do with sets [for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103930/issues-with-defbibentryset) but I dont know how to adapt the solutions I have seen for removing the titles from the footnotes of the set

Problem 2: I would like the grouped citations to collapse together so they display as 1a-c,e or 1a,c not 1a,1b,1c...

Problem 3: I notice I have lost the space before the journal title...

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft=true,11pt, openany]{scrbook}
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=chem-acs,
maxnames=10,
sorting=none, subentry,
citetracker,
pagetracker=page,
doi=false,
articletitle=true,
maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
% \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\fnsymbol {footnote}]}
%\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{doi: \detokenize{#1}}}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearfield{note}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}%
}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}  %removes title from footnote

\usepackage[hypertex,debug=true]{hyperref}

%bibliography source
\begin{filecontents}{job.bib}
    @article{van2000ligand,
        title={Ligand bite angle effects in metal-catalyzed C- C bond formation},
        author={van Leeuwen, Piet WNM and Kamer, Paul CJ and Reek, Joost NH and Dierkes, Peter},
        journal={chemrev},
        volume={100},
        number={8},
        pages={2741--2770},
        year={2000},
        doi={10.1021/cr9902704}
    }

    @article{Qadir2002,
        title={Examination of ligand effects in the Heck arylation reaction},
        author={Qadir, Maryiam and M{\"o}chel, Tobias and Hii, King Kuok Mimi},
        journal={Tetrahedron},
        volume={56},
        number={40},
        pages={7975--7979},
        year={2000},
        doi={10.1016/S0040-4020(00)00703-1}
    }

    @article{Shao2016,
        title={Lanthanide-Catalyzed Reversible Alkynyl Exchange by Carbon--Carbon Single-Bond Cleavage Assisted by a Secondary Amino Group},
        author={Shao, Yinlin and Zhang, Fangjun and Zhang, Jie and Zhou, Xigeng},
        journal={Angewandte Chemie},
        volume={128},
        number={38},
        pages={11657--11661},
        year={2016},
        doi={10.1002/anie.201605822}
    }

    @article{yao2004,
        title={AuCl3-catalyzed synthesis of highly substituted furans from 2-(1-alkynyl)-2-alken-1-ones},
        author={Yao, Tuanli and Zhang, Xiaoxia and Larock, Richard C},
        journal={Journal of the American Chemical Society},
        volume={126},
        number={36},
        pages={11164--11165},
        year={2004},
        doi={10.1021/ja0466964}
    }

    @article{Cella1984,
        author = {Cella, James A. and Bacon, Sidney W.},
        title = {Preparation of dialkyl carbonates via the phase-transfer-catalyzed alkylation of alkali metal carbonate and bicarbonate salts},
        journal = {The Journal of Organic Chemistry},
        volume = {49},
        number = {6},
        pages = {1122-1125},
        year = {1984},
        doi = {10.1021/jo00180a033}
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{job.bib}


%%%%%Footnoteing%%%%%%
\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}  %citation foot notes
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[fnsymbol]    %intext footnotes  \footnoteB{<text>}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol {footnote}} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Making autocite=superscript also go into footnote section%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69249/biblatex-citation-appears-with-different-reference-marks%
\makeatletter
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\cbx@superscript]%
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
    \ifciteseen{}{\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
            \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\cbx@superscript]% Use cite when citing a reference from a grouped citation at innitial use)
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}


\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\cbx@superscript]{\cite}{}


\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
    \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
    \cbx@citehook%
    \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \defbibentryset{bibset}{van2000ligand, Qadir2002, Shao2016, yao2004}
    bibset\autocite{bibset}

    citation of 1st, 2nd and 3rd\cites{van2000ligand, Qadir2002, Shao2016}

    other\autocite{Cella1984}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: text]
[image: footnote]
[image: Bibliography]

Comment: Dont worry about the request, I realised I was had draft mode on for the document or wasn't using `\usepackage[**final**,hypertex,debug=true]{hyperref}`. I have gotten hyperlinks to work mostly how I want

Comment: I guess another way to ask the first problem (which might also solve the third problem) is it possible to only turn on the title when the bibliography is being printed?